# Everscale tonos-cli. Can't deploy a contract. Error: failed to create inbound message: Encode deploy message failed: Wrong parameters count

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, everscale

I can't deploy compiled free ton solidity smartcontract through tonos-cli.

```
> tonos-cli deploy Hello.tvc tonos-cli.conf.json

Config: /ton/solidity_deploy/hello/tonos-cli.conf.json
Input arguments:
     tvc: Hello.tvc
  params: {""url"":""https://main.ton.dev"",""wc"":-1,""addr"":null,""wallet"":null,""abi_path"":""Hello.abi.json"",""keys_path"":""keyfile.json"",""retries"":3,""timeout"":600,""is_json"":false,""depool_fee"":0.5,""lifetime"":3600,""no_answer"":true,""use_delimiters"":true,""local_run"":true}
     abi: Hello.abi.json
    keys: keyfile.json
      wc: None
Connecting to https://main.ton.dev
Deploying...
Error: failed to create inbound message: Encode deploy message failed: Wrong parameters count. Expected: 0, provided: 14
Error: 1
```

ends with error. My config is:

```
❯ tonos-cli config --list

Config: /ton/solidity_deploy/hello/tonos-cli.conf.json
{
  ""url"": ""https://main.ton.dev"",
  ""wc"": -1,
  ""addr"": null,
  ""wallet"": null,
  ""abi_path"": ""Hello.abi.json"",
  ""keys_path"": ""keyfile.json"",
  ""retries"": 3,
  ""timeout"": 600,
  ""is_json"": false,
  ""depool_fee"": 0.5,
  ""lifetime"": 3600,
  ""no_answer"": true,
  ""use_delimiters"": true,
  ""local_run"": true
}
```

Does anybody know what is wrong? I do it as written in the manual. Config was generated as written in the repo. Probably the problem is in parameters.."

Answer (score 0):

The params meaning params in the contract constructor. You have 0 params in the constructor (Expected: 0), so you need to write "{}".

If tonos-cli.conf.json is in the current directory you don`t need to write --config tonos-cli.conf.json in the command line.

Fix quotes in tonos-cli.conf.json: from "" to "
and
try this:
`tonos-cli deploy Hello.tvc "{}"`